# Rails N + 1 query problem when fetching associated records with where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have below table structure. This is just an example

`UserPost  => user_id, post_id, Post, Comment`

So, If I try to fetch all `user_posts` using the below query and do where on the `comments` table then it fires query for the `comments` table

```
user_posts = UserPost.includes(post: :comments)
user_posts.each do |up|
  post = up.post # No Query
  comments = up.comments # No query
  comments_with_condition = up.comments.where(visibility: true).order(position: :asc).first.data # Fires query for .where and .order as well.
end
```

So, is this the expected behavior or I am doing something wrong?

How to prevent the query for each `user_post`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is add another `has_many` to your model with a filter of what you want.

```rb
# You can name this anything you want but a descriptive name helps
has_many :special_comments, -> { where(visibility: true).order(..) }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

...and eager load that in your query which will eager load both type of comments. This will inevitably lead to one extra query, but it is not N+1.

```rb
user_post = UserPost.includes(post: [:comments, :special_comments])

user_posts.each do |user_post|
  post = user_post.post
  comments = user_post.comments
  comments_with_condition = user_post.special_comments
end
```